# Outlook - Formatting with pass through rectangle with different color

Tags: microsoft-outlook

This information is hard to search so pardon me if it is duplicate.

How do I create this background formatting in outlook, where I get a perfect rectangular background ( it is not a table with one row and one column) and you can actually select these just a few of them inside and outside if you know what I mean.

there is another one with a red line on the format and not the text itself. How to do that?

[image]

Comment: Really did a lot of search but have not found any template similar to this. I'm afraid that this might be achieved via codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it
[How to send programming code snippets in Outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/722929/how-to-send-programming-code-snippets-in-outlook)

[image]